# Empty response object in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, body-parser

I am trying to get all documents in mongo collection but instead i am getting empty response. my database name is taskDb which has a collection named item in which all the documents are stored. I think maybe there is some problem with schema but mongo is schema less db so i am not able to find the solution.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

Items = require('./items.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/taskDb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get("/",(req, res)=> {
    res.send('Visit /api/*****');
});

app.get("/api/items",(req, res)=> {
    Items.getItems(function(err, items){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(res.json(items));
        res.json(items);
    });
});

// app.get("/api/matches",(req, res)=> {
//     Matches.getMatches(function(err, matches){
//         if(err){
//             throw err;
//         }
//         res.json(matches);
//     });
// });

// app.get("/api/deliveries/:playerName",(req, res)=> {
//     Deliveries.getPlayerStats(req.params.playerName ,function(err, deliveries){
//         if(err){
//             throw err;
//         }
//         res.json(deliveries);
//     });
// });

app.listen(3005,()=>{
   console.log('Listening on port 3005...');
});
```

item.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _ID:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ITEM:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    KEY:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    STATUS:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);

// module.exports.getPlayerStats = function (playerName, callback) {
//     Deliveries.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 1,batsman: 1 ,batsman_runs: 1, dismissal:{
//         $cond: [ { $eq: ["$player_dismissed", playerName ] }, 1, 0]
//     }}},{ $match: { batsman: playerName } },
//     { $group: {_id: "$batsman", total_runs: { $sum: "$batsman_runs" },total_dismissal: { $sum: "$dismissal"}}}
//     ], callback);
// }

module.exports.getItems = function (callback, limit) {
    Item.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I see in `getItems` function:

1. Condition for `find()` is not specified. In case you want to read all records, you can specify it as empty object.
2. Limit parameter is not being passed from your request handler to `getItems` function. You would either need to default it to some number or handle the scenario where `limit` won't be passed.

Modifying `getItems()` to something like below should work:

```
module.exports.getItems = function (callback, limit) {
    Item.find({}, callback).limit(limit || 20); // Default limit to a feasible number
};
```

Also, you can pass limit to `getItems()` function from request handler if you want to override default:

```
app.get("/api/items",(req, res)=> {
    Items.getItems(function(err, items){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(res.json(items));
        return res.json(items);
    }, 50); // Pass limit
});
```